# Javascript jQuery .change(); event. на Input[type="file"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы, input, события

Приведу пример простого кода

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="input">
<button id="click">CLICK</button>

<script>

    (function(){

        var input = $('#input'),
            click = $('#click');

        input.change(
            function()
            {
                click.click(
                    function()
                    {
                        console.log('here');
                    }
                );
            }
        );

    })();


</script>
```

Код легкий, все понятно.
Мне нужно сделать, когда происходит input.change(); event, чтобы включался клик.
При нажатии на клик, естественно в данном случае, даст console.log('here'); 'here'.
Вроде все работает, только тогда когда выбираю файл 1 раз, но если я выберу файл 2 раза и нажму на клик, то тогда, в консоли отобразятся 2 клика (2)here.
как сделать чтобы 1 раз было?
Я привел простой пример, чтобы было понятно.
а продакшен код в 400 строк, цель которого, при выборе файла отображать его, и после клика на кнопку загружать его, то так как при выборе файла 2 раза внутри все происходит 2 раза, если 3 раза то 3 раза и.т.д.
загружаются все выбранные файлы.

Спасибо

Продакшен код:

```
window.App.Module.Partial.Photo =
{
    OBJ :
    {
        Window                      : {},
        Document                    : {},
        Body                        : {},
        ProfilePhotoBox             : {},
        ProfilePhotoImage           : {},
        ProfilePhotoPreview         : {},
        PhotoSettingContainer       : {},
        PhotoSetting                : {},
        PhotoSettingBox             : {},
        ProgressBar                 : {},
        ProfilePhotoUploadInput     : {},
        ProfilePhotoRenderContainer : {},
        ProfilePhotoRenderBox       : {},
        ProfilePhotoRenderImage     : {},
        ProfilePhotoRenderLoader    : {},
        ProfilePhotoRenderCancel    : {},
        ProfilePhotoUploadForm      : {},
        PhotoDeleteForm             : {},
    },

    Init : function()
    {
        this.OBJ.Window                      = window;
        this.OBJ.Document                    = document;
        this.OBJ.Body                        = $('body');
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoBox             = $('#profile-photo-box');
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoImage           = '#profile-photo-image';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview         = '#profile-photo-preview';
        this.OBJ.PhotoSettingContainer       = $('#photo-setting-container');
        this.OBJ.PhotoSetting                = '#photo-setting';
        this.OBJ.PhotoSettingBox             = '#photo-setting-box';
        this.OBJ.ProgressBar                 = $('#progress-bar');
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoUploadInput     = '#profile-photo-upload-input';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderContainer = '#profile-photo-render-container';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderBox       = '#profile-photo-render-box';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderImage     = '#profile-photo-render-image';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderLoader    = '#profile-photo-render-loader';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderCancel    = '#profile-photo-render-cancel';
        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoUploadForm      = '#profile-photo-upload-form';
        this.OBJ.PhotoDeleteForm             = '#photo-delete-form';

        this.SetProfileImage();
        this.SetProfilePhotoBox();
    },

    SetProfileImage : function()
    {
        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoImage).fadeIn(0);
    },

    SetProfilePhotoBox :  function()
    {
        this.ListenProfilePhotoBox();
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoBox :  function()
    {
        var th    = this,
            cache = false;

        this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoBox.click(
            function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (cache) return;
                cache = true;
                $(this).blur();

                th.SetPhotoSettingContainer();

                setTimeout(
                    function()
                    {
                        cache = false;
                    }, 200
                );
            }
        );
    },

    SetPhotoSettingContainer :  function()
    {
        this.GetPhotoSetting();
    },

    RemovePhotoSettingContainer :  function()
    {
        this.RemoveProfilePhotoPreview();
        this.RemovePhotoSetting();
        this.RemoveBody();
    },

    SetPhotoSetting :  function()
    {
        $(this.OBJ.PhotoSetting).fadeIn(80);
        this.SetBody();
        this.SetProfilePhotoInputChange();
        this.SetProfilePhotoDeleteForm();
    },

    GetPhotoSetting :  function()
    {
        var th = this;

        new GET(
            {
                URL      : this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoBox.prop('href'),
                GE1      : this.OBJ.PhotoSettingContainer,
                Loader   : this.OBJ.ProgressBar,
                Callback : this.ListenPhotoSetting.bind(this)
            }
        );
    },

    RemovePhotoSetting :  function()
    {
        $(this.OBJ.PhotoSetting).parent(this.OBJ.PhotoSettingContainer).html('');
    },

    ListenPhotoSetting : function()
    {
        this.SetPhotoSetting();
    },

    SetBody : function()
    {
        this.OBJ.Body.addClass('veil');
        this.SetWindow();
    },

    RemoveBody : function()
    {
        $(this.OBJ.Body).removeClass('veil');
    },

    SetWindow : function()
    {
        this.ListenWindow();
    },

    ListenWindow : function()
    {
        var th = this;

        $(this.OBJ.Window).resize(
            function()
            {
                $(th.OBJ.PhotoSettingBox).css(
                    {
                        top: (
                            ($(this).outerHeight() / 2) -
                            ($(th.OBJ.PhotoSettingBox).outerHeight() / 2)
                        )
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        $(this.OBJ.Window).trigger('resize');

        $(th.OBJ.Window).on('keyup.RemovePhotoSettingContainer',
            function(event)
            {
                if (event.which == 27) {
                    th.RemovePhotoSettingContainer(event);
                    $(this).off('click.RemovePhotoSettingContainer');
                    $(this).off('keyup.RemovePhotoSettingContainer');
                }
            }
        ).on('click.RemovePhotoSettingContainer',
            function(event)
            {
                if ( $(event.target).closest($(th.OBJ.PhotoSettingBox)).length ) return;
                if ( $(event.target).closest($(th.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderContainer)).length ) return;
                th.RemovePhotoSettingContainer(event);
                $(this).off('click.RemovePhotoSettingContainer');
                $(this).off('keyup.RemovePhotoSettingContainer');
            }
        );
    },

    SetProfilePhotoInputChange : function()
    {
        this.ListenProfilePhotoInputChange();
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoInputChange : function()
    {
        var th = this;

        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoUploadInput).click(
            function ()
            {
                this.value = null;
            }
        ).change(
            function(event)
            {
                $(this).blur();
                th.SetProfilePhotoRenderContainer(event);
            }
        );

    },

    SetProfilePhotoRenderContainer : function(event)
    {
        var th    = this,
            photo = event.target.files[0];

        if (!photo) {
            return new Message(
                {
                    MSG    : 'File is not found',
                    Output : '#g-messages',
                    Status : 'g-m-error'
                }
            );
        }

        if (photo.size > 1e+7) {
            return new Message(
                {
                    MSG    : 'File upload max size is 10 MB',
                    Output : '#g-messages',
                    Status : 'g-m-error'
                }
            );
        }

        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderContainer).fadeIn('slow');
        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderLoader).fadeIn(0);

        this.SetProfilePhotoRender(photo);
    },

    RemoveProfilePhotoRenderContainer : function()
    {
        this.RemoveProfilePhotoPreview();
        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderContainer).fadeOut(0);
        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderImage).prop('src', '');
    },

    SetProfilePhotoRender : function(photo)
    {
        this.ListenProfilePhotoRender(photo);
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoRender : function(photo)
    {
        var th          = this,
            reader      = new FileReader(),
            imageBase64 = '';

        reader.onload = function(event) {
            imageBase64 = (
                'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +
                btoa(event.target.result)
            );
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(photo);

        setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                $(th.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderImage).prop('src', imageBase64);
                th.SetProfilePhotoRenderImageCropper();
                $(th.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderLoader).fadeOut(0);
            }, 500
        );
    },

    SetProfilePhotoRenderImageCropper : function()
    {
        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview).addClass('profile-photo-preview-visible');
        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview).fadeIn(200);

        var cropper = new Cropper(
            this.OBJ.Document.querySelector(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderImage),
            {
                aspectRatio : 1 / 1,
                viewMode    : 1,
                preview     : this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview
            }
        );

        this.ListenProfilePhotoRenderImageCropper(cropper);
    },

    RemoveProfilePhotoRenderImageCropper :  function(cropper)
    {
        cropper.destroy();
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoRenderImageCropper : function(cropper)
    {
        var th = this;

        cropper.getCroppedCanvas(
            {
                fillColor : '#fff'
            }
        ).toBlob(
            function(fileBlob)
            {
                th.SetProfilePhotoUploadForm(fileBlob);
            }, "image/jpeg", 0.8
        );

        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoRenderCancel).on('click.ProfilePhotoRenderCancel',
            function()
            {
                th.RemoveProfilePhotoRenderImageCropper(cropper);
                th.RemoveProfilePhotoRenderContainer();
                $(this).off('click.ProfilePhotoRenderCancel');
            }
        );

    },

    SetProfilePhotoUploadForm :  function(fileBlob)
    {
        this.ListenProfilePhotoUploadForm(fileBlob);
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoUploadForm :  function(fileBlob)
    {
        var th = this;

        console.log(fileBlob);

        $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoUploadForm).on('submit.ProfilePhotoUploadForm',
            function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                th.SetProfilePhotoUpload(this, fileBlob);
                $(this).off('submit.ProfilePhotoUploadForm');
            }
        );
    },

    SetProfilePhotoUpload : function(form, fileBlob)
    {
        new Post(
            {
                Form      : form,
                Loader    : this.OBJ.ProgressBar,
                FilePhoto : fileBlob,
                PE1       : this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoBox,
                PE2       : this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoImage,
                Callback  : this.ListenProfilePhotoUpload.bind(this),
            }
        );
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoUpload : function(response)
    {
        if (response.status === 'view') {
            this.RemovePhotoSettingContainer();
        }
    },

    RemoveProfilePhotoPreview : function()
    {
        if ($(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview).filter(':visible')) {
            $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview).fadeOut(0).html('');
        }
        if ($(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview).hasClass('profile-photo-preview-visible')) {
            $(this.OBJ.ProfilePhotoPreview).removeClass('profile-photo-preview-visible');
        }
    },

    SetProfilePhotoDeleteForm : function()
    {
        this.ListenProfilePhotoDeleteForm();
    },

    ListenProfilePhotoDeleteForm : function()
    {
        var th = this;

        $(this.OBJ.PhotoDeleteForm).submit(
            function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                new Post(
                    {
                        Form      : this,
                        Loader    : th.OBJ.ProgressBar,
                        PE1       : th.OBJ.ProfilePhotoBox,
                        PE2       : th.OBJ.ProfilePhotoImage,
                        Callback  : function(response)
                        {
                            if (response.status === 'view') {
                                th.RemovePhotoSettingContainer();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: это все потому, что при каждом выборе файла **добавляется обработчик клика для кнопки**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

    (function(){

        var input = $('#input'),
            click = $('#click');

        input.change(
            function()
            {
                click
                    .off('click')
                    .on('click',
                    function()
                    {
                        console.log('here');
                    }
                );
            }
        );

    })();


</script>
```

Это как самый простой вариант....

Comment: самый простой было добавлять атрибут `disabled` кнопке - а не тыркать обработчики туда сюда одинаковые

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Согласен, изначально не правильный подход, но весь код мы де не видим может вариант с атрибутом в случае продакшн кода не подходит?

Comment: сделаю правку, впишу весь код.